# JavaFX in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I want to run a code that uses JavaFX in IntelliJ 2019, every time I try to run it shows an error:

***Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application***

How can I solve this problem? I am using JDK 12.0.1

Comment: Have you seen https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij?

Answer (score 0):

Java FX is no longer packaged with the Java runtime after JDK 10. You must download and package the Jar with JavaFX runtime, see https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ in order to learn how best to get this up and running.

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136420/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javafx-application-application